# xsl - create nested structure for tags that start with prefix

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that has certain tags that start with prefix "OneTwo":

```
<Root>
  <Element>
    <OneTwoTag1>value1</OneTwoTag1>
    <OneTwoTag2>value2</OneTwoTag2>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <OneTwoTag1>value1</OneTwoTag1>
    <OneTwoTag2>value2</OneTwoTag2>
  </Element>
<Root>
```

I want them to be duplicated into a nested structure so that output XML will look like the following:

```
<Root>
  <Element>
    <OneTwoTag1>value1</OneTwoTag1>
    <OneTwoTag2>value2</OneTwoTag2>
    <OneTwo>
      <TwoTag1>value1</TwoTag1>
      <TwoTag2>value2</TwoTag2>
    </OneTwo>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <OneTwoTag1>value1</OneTwoTag1>
    <OneTwoTag2>value2</OneTwoTag2>
    <OneTwo>
      <TwoTag1>value1</TwoTag1>
      <TwoTag2>value2</TwoTag2>
    </OneTwo>
  </Element>
<Root>
```

I have tried following XSLT, but to no avail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[starts-with(name(),'Root/Element/OneTwo')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:element name="OneTwo">
                <xsl:element name="{substring(name(),4)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PS: I am very new to XSLT.

Comment: I only glanced at this but one thing stands out: to select elements whose name starts with "OneTwo" you need to use `*[starts-with(name(), 'OneTwo')]`. -- P.S. This is not a "prefix" (this term is used for prefixes bound to a namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Element">
        <Element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <OneTwo>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'OneTwo')]">
                    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(),4)}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </OneTwo>
        </Element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```